# formGroup must be in lowercase - Angular

Tags: angular, forms

I'm receiving an error message that states the attribute name of [formGroup] must be in lowercase. This error is commonly encountered when using Angular's ngIf and ngFor directives. Although I have updated the syntax as recommended, the error message remains, even though the directives continue to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have imported Reactive Form Module in your app.ts file
and also included it in @ngModules imports

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

as you have not mentioned much in questions i got this problem if anything else plz edit and do comment ill try my best just try to comment the excat error you are getting.